# How to invoke commands directly from the main Click Group

Tags: python, command-line-interface, python-click

I'm trying to write a python module using [Click](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/).
In the module, I have a `main` group that has two commands, `func1` and `func2`.
`func1` and `func2` accepts user input as parameters.

```
import click


@click.group(invoke_without_command=True)
def main():
    pass


@main.command()
@click.option('--text', prompt='Enter a word')
def func1(text):
    click.echo(f'Func1 is called and the input is {text}')


@main.command()
@click.option('--text', prompt='Enter another word')
def func2(text):

    click.echo(f'Func2 is called and the input is {text}')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I want to call `func1` and `func2` one by one once the module is called. More details, when I call the module, the result should be like this:

```
Func1 is called and the input is word
Func2 is called and the input is anotherword
```

Currently, I can call the module with command name (`python tool.py func1`) and only that command executes. I tried:

```
# rest of the code

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
    main.func1()
```

but no luck.

My aim to call the module and run the commands one by one without passing the commands name while calling the module. Is there any help how can I do this or what is the robust way to achieve this?

I have some experience of working with JavaScript, but I'm new to Python.
Any help would definitely be appreciated.
Many thanks

Comment: It's still not clear why you're trying to implement these as separate commands. If they must always run in sequence, just have a single command (`main`) and have it call two separate *functions*.

Comment: can you please give a minimum example? do you mean I should not use `click.group`?